# Python script is returning empty data frame for geo_enabled field in tweets

Tags: python, pandas, twitter

In my Python script I am trying to display `geo_enabled` value of a given set of streamed tweets. In case `geo_enabled` is `false` I would like to display it as `false` or `true` otherwise and I would also like to display `place` and `country` tags as `null` if the corresponding values are not filled by the person tweeting. The problem is that I am currently stuck as my script keeps throwing a `KeyError`.

I am under the impression that `KeyError` is being generated as `geo_enabled` has `false` as a value. Any work around this.

My python script :

```
import time
import json
import pandas as pd
import re

#tweepy based modules
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener


#initializing authentication credentials
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_key = ''
access_secret = ''


#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener) :
    def __init__(self,time_limit) :
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.limit = time_limit
        self.saveFile = open('requests.json','a')
        super(StdOutListener,self).__init__()

    def on_data(self, data) :
        if ((time.time() - self.start_time) < self.limit) :
            self.saveFile.write(data)
            self.saveFile.write('\n')
            return True
        else :
            self.saveFile.close()
            return False

    def on_error(self, status) :
        print(status)

def getwords(string) :
    return re.findall(r"[\w'#]+|[.,!?;]",string)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)

    time_limit = input("Enter the time limit in minutes : ")
    time_limit *= 60

    stream = Stream(auth,listener = StdOutListener(time_limit))
    string = raw_input("Enter the list of keywords/hashtags to be compared : ")

    keyword_list = getwords(string)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
    stream.filter(track = keyword_list)

    tweets_data_path = 'requests.json'

    tweets_data = []
    tweet_list = []

    tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")

    for i, line in enumerate(tweets_file) :
        if line.rstrip() :
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            tweet_list.append(tweet)

    num_tweets_collected = len(tweet_list)
    count = 0

    #Creates a data frame structure
    text_dump = open('text_dump.txt', 'w')


    #Populating the location field of the data frame

    #tweet_dataframe['location'] = map(lambda tweet : tweet['location'], tweet_list)
    #print(tweet_dataframe['location'])

    #index column for data frame
    index_dataframe = []

    for i in range(0, num_tweets_collected) :
        index_dataframe.append(i)

    tweet_text = [tweet['text'].encode('utf-8') for tweet in tweet_list]
    tweet_text_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(tweet_text, index = index_dataframe, columns = ['text'])

    tweet_geolocation_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
    tweet_geolocation_dataframe['geo_enabled'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['geo_enabled'] if tweet['geo_enabled'] != "false" else "false", tweet_list)

    tweet_text_ = tweet_text_dataframe['text']

    print(tweet_geolocation_dataframe['geo_enabled'])
```

Output :

```
abhijeet-mohanty-2:Desktop SubrataMohanty$ python twitter_stream_dump.py 
Enter the time limit in minutes : 1
Enter the list of keywords/hashtags to be compared : python ruby scala
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_stream_dump.py", line 94, in <module>
    tweet_geolocation_dataframe['geo_enabled'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['geo_enabled'] if tweet['geo_enabled'] != "false" else "false", tweet_list)
  File "twitter_stream_dump.py", line 94, in <lambda>
    tweet_geolocation_dataframe['geo_enabled'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['geo_enabled'] if tweet['geo_enabled'] != "false" else "false", tweet_list)
KeyError: 'geo_enabled'
```

Edits :

So I made the following changes to my Python script but an **empty** data frame is returned.

I replaced the following line -

```
tweet_geolocation_dataframe['geo_enabled'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['geo_enabled'] if tweet['geo_enabled'] != "false" else "false", tweet_list)
```

with the lines below :

```
for tweet in tweet_list :
    if 'geo_enabled' in tweet :   
        tweet_geolocation_dataframe['geo_enabled'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['geo_enabled'] if tweet['geo_enabled'] != "false" else "false", tweet_list)
    else: 
        tweet_geolocation_dataframe['geo_enabled'] = False
```

Output :

```
abhijeet-mohanty-2:Desktop SubrataMohanty$ python twitter_stream_dump.py 
Enter the time limit in minutes : 1
Enter the list of keywords/hashtags to be compared : python ruby scala
Series([], Name: geo_enabled, dtype: bool)
```

Any way to solve the problem of **empty** data frame for `geo_enabled` field.

Comment: You need to show us the stack trace where your program is failing.

Comment: @BoarGules I have put up the output I am getting.

Comment: You get KeyError NOT because geo_enabled has a false value But geo_enabled does not exist in tweet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
 if 'geo_enabled' in tweet:   
     tweet_geolocation_dataframe['geo_enabled'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['geo_enabled'] if tweet['geo_enabled'] != "false" else "false", tweet_list)
 else:
     tweet_geolocation_dataframe['geo_enabled'] = False
```

Comment: It returns an empty data frame.

Comment: Could you help?